# Said Chatzi Kadish in error - can it be corrected?

Tags: halacha, mistakes, kaddish

If the Chazan at some point in Davening says the wrong Kaddish and then at a later point realizes his error, can anything be done to rectify his error?

For example: this morning - which was Rosh Chodesh Elul - I Davened in a Shul where the Chazan after Hallel instead of saying Kadish Shalaim said Chatzi Kaddish in error, and no one corrected him. In middle of Kriyas haTorah he realized his error. Would the Chazan be able to do anything at that point to rectify his error?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21831

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33335

Answer (score 4):

[HaRav HaGaon Yakov Ariel says](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=52921) that he does not go back:

> לתשובות נוספות של הרה"ג יעקב אריאל
>
> שאלה:
>   חזן שטעה ובמקום קדיש תתקבל אמר חצי קדיש, האם חוזר?
>   ובחנוכה ור"ח שחל בחול אם טעה כדלעיל והתחילו לקרוא בתורה - כיצד ינהג?‏
>
> תשובה:
>   אינו חוזר.‏

Also see http://www.moreshet.co.il/web/shut/print.asp?id=139465&kod=&modul=15&codeClient=58 
from  HaRav Avraham Yosef   תשובה מאת הרב אברהם יוסף who also says don't go back.

Comment: Can he do anything to rectify the error?

Comment: HaRav Avraham Yosef says to rely on Kaddish Titkabel of Musaf to be effective also for Shaharit.

Answer (score 3):

Rav Eliezer Melamed ([Peninei Halacha Tefillah 23:2 fn3](http://ph.yhb.org.il/02-23-02/)) quotes Ishei Yisrael 26:11 who says that "Tiakabel" etc. should be recited **during the next Kaddish**.  (This was said in the case where one missed the Kaddish Shalem after Uva Letzion, but would likely apply to any missed Kadish Shalem where you have already finished the Tefillah associated with Tiskabel.)

For the opposite case (where one said Kaddish Shalem after Tachanun, etc), he quotes Ishei Yisrael 26:5 who says to skip the "Tiskabel line" when Kaddish Shalem would have been said.