# Difference in structure between Maariv Motzaei Shabbos vs. Purim and Tisha Beav

Tags: tefilla, purim, kaddish, tisha-bav, motzei-shabbos

This question is for Nusach Artscroll Ashkenaz, and anyone else who follows the same sequence.  I believe this includes the Ezras Torah luach.

On Motzaei Shabbos, Purim, and Tisha Beav, Maariv gets (vihi noam and) uva letziyon added to it, but the sequence is different:

Motzaei Shabbos:

- shemoneh esrei
- **chatzi kaddish**
- vihi noam and uva letziyon
- **kaddish shalem**

Purim and Tisha Beav

- shemoneh esrei
- **kaddish shalem**
- (Esther|Eicha and kinnot)
- (vihi noam if it's Purim Motzaei Shabbos and) uva letziyon
- **kaddish that's identical to kaddish yatom but said by the chazzan**

Why the difference?

Comment: The simple answer here is Artscroll's Minhag is wrong, and there should be a Chatzi Kaddish after the Amida at Maariv on Purim (this is the position of the Levush, Taz, etc.). But I assume you don't want that as an answer.

Comment: While you're adding these unusuals, I believe that there is also a half Kaddish on Simchat Torah just before "Arthur Racer".

Comment: @DoubleAA See Mishnah Berurah commentary #4 to O.C. 559:1. He says that after Ma'ariv, i.e. the Amidah, the chazzan says Kaddish with Titkabel. I don't know what Art Scroll says, as I don't have it before me. But, if A.S. instructs to say Kaddish Titkabel, it is correct based on this *shita*.

Comment: I have to check what happens on Purim night. But, I think that after *Ve'ata Kaddosh*, the chazzan says full Kaddish with Titkabel, but on 9 Av, not (reason being that on 9 Av), we eliminate *Titkabel* in all Kaddish from after Eicha until, I think Mincha following day.) The reason for double Kaddish (almost) Shalem twice is that the 1st is for after the Amidah. The 2nd is that, I think *Kedusha Desidrah* warrants its own Kaddish Titkabel, similar to what happens during Shacharit. There's a reason why we don't say one after Shachrit Amidah. I have to compile this from BeureiHatefillah.com

Comment: Likely this derives from places that would Daven Maariv early as usual on Purim night, and then wait for proper nightfall for the Megillah, a custom noted in Matte Moshe 801 http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42401&st=&pgnum=197 and in Maharil Purim 5. Notably, the old custom was to say Titkabbal twice. Skipping it the second time through is a later change to try and make the practice reasonable.